# get Meteor.subscribe in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I have this code,

```
Meteor.subscribe('getOrgDetail', {status:'active'},function(){
        var sub = this;
        self.setState({'subscriptions.orgs':sub{id:Organizations.find().fetch()});
    });
```

I am using this, to get the Meteor.subscribe in callback. But it is not working. Is there any other way to setState the subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing things. You basically only need the subscription object if you want to `.stop()` the subscription.

When the last argument to `.subscribe()` is a function, it is interpreted as the `onReady()` callback.

The `this` context of the callback will not be the subscription object. It will be whatever is the owning context where the function is called, as usual in Javascript. And in the case of a Meteor subscription onReady callback this is not defined.

So in the callback you cannot rely on `this`, only on variables you have in your scope or closures (like your `self`).

If you want to do a `.find()` when the subscription is ready, what you should do is set a state flag signalling that it is, and then have a function that depends on the value of this state flag that does the `.find()` on the **collection** object, not the subscription object.

```
self.setState( { getOrgDetailReady: true } );
```

then in one of the lifecycle methods that run when state changes (which one depends on your code...) you do:

```
if( this.state.getOrgDetailReady ) {
    let orgDetails = orgDetailCollection.find().fetch();
    ...
}
```

Comment: How can I set a state flag to execute a function if the subscription is ready?

Comment: I put an example of this at the end of the answer.